# Can Pycharm be used in animation node script?

Tags: animation-nodes

Hil all,

i set pycharm up to write code for blender.
I can read code from blender text editor from pycharm and the console in blender prints out correctly, but i dont get any output from the script node in animation node.
Has someone a solution to use pycharm to work in animation node script?
Pycharm

[image]

Blender

[image]

[image]

Comment: After you edited your script in PyCharm, you need to reload it inside blender with Text > Reload or ALT + R

Comment: That does nothing sorry. I guess it wouldnt print anything in the blender console without reading the input from pycharm but it print the output in the blender console.....only animation node script dont recognize it. Have you managed it to work ?

Comment: From what I can see in your screenshots everything is working as expected. Animation Nodes scripts only read text blocks which are open in blender

Comment: Have you managed it to work Gorgious ?

Comment: I think you don't understand. In all of your screenshots I don't see any error or unexpected behaviour. What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I guess i understand know what you try by telling me Alt + R.Just use the py file inside blender text editor and reload it when changes where made in pycharm and not read the py file from another py file inside the text editor.